# How to save values from GSuite card form

Tags: settings, google-workspace

I'll lead into this saying:  This is my first Stack Overflow post, and I am also new to G Suite Add-On development, so please bear with me.  I am working on a G Suite AddOn to extend GMail to work with another application's API.  I am adding a Settings card using the Universal Actions instructions as provided by Google in this URL:  https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions

My question is:  I have the settings and about cards working, however:  If I were using the settings card to collect a username/server URL for the 3rd party API Connection, how do I go about saving what is entered in the settings card to be used by the GMail Addon for connection properties?

Thank you in advance.

--Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  Thank you to anyone who took a look.  Using the PropertiesService I am able to save User and Script properties.